# Routing in ASP .NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I created a web service using WEB API.

I'm using this routing configuration

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And my solution include two controller (`ProductController` and `DetailController`)

So when I want to call a WS that refers to the GetDetails method(is located inside DetailController) I have to use a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/api/Details/GetDetails/?id=4
```

Is there a way for use, for the same request, this URL instead:

```
http://localhost/api/Product/GetDetails/?id=4
```

letting the GetDetails method inside the DetailController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your urls should be:

```
http://localhost/api/Details/4
http://localhost/api/Products/4
```

and your controllers:

```
public class DetailsController: ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class ProductsController: ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now that's RESTful.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind using query parameter instead of the url itself to represent the resource (ie `http://localhost/api/Details/4`). It doesn't seem "RESTful".

Comment: You are right. It's prettier to have `/{id}` in this case. But this doesn't mean at all that query string parameters are not RESTful. Usually when I have optional parameters I pass them as query string parameters. This usually makes sense in GET requests which need to take multiple parameters. But I agree with you that the identifier which identifies the resource is better to be passed in the path portion.

Comment: No, I understand the use case for query parameter. It just seemed like the id (in this case) was meant to represent a resource uniquely.

Comment: Completely agree with you. I have updated my answer to take your remark into account.